# delete[] giving heap corruption detected

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am getting an error of heap corruption detected when specifically calling my delete in main. But I clearly see that my values in my dynamically allocated array are being displayed. I checked out a few other articles but I am getting confused about my specific case as to what I have done wrong. The dynamically allocated array is supposed to contain array elements of original array that are greater than or equal to 10. This is why 11 and 13 display when outputting array elements in new dynamically allocated array.All help fixing this problem is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <new>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

bool interesting(unsigned n);
unsigned * cull(unsigned & intEls, const unsigned ar[], unsigned els);

int main(){
    unsigned ar1[5] = { 3,5,7,11,13 };
    unsigned size;
    unsigned * result = cull(size,ar1,5);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << result[i];
    }
    delete[] result;
}

bool interesting(unsigned n){
    if (n >= 10)
        return true;
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

unsigned * cull(unsigned & intEls, const unsigned ar[], unsigned els){
    intEls = 0;
    unsigned * array = new unsigned[intEls];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < els; i++) {
        if (interesting(ar[i])) {
            array[intEls++] = ar[i];        
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Here `new unsigned[intEls];` you are allocating an array of size 0.

Comment: Generally speaking, with C++98 you should see `new` in class constructors, `delete` in destructors, and very little of those two keywords elsewhere. With C++11, you should be using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). Do go ahead and learn what went wrong with your program here, but then do yourself the favor and learn how to avoid the whole issue of manual memory management altogether.

Comment: `std::vector` would be the standard recommendation.

Comment: @paddy: I haven't actually looked into what the OP was doing there. Too painful. ;-) But yes, [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for the win as well.

Comment: `delete []` doesn't corrupt memory, the act of writing to `array[intEls++]` can potentially corrupt the heap, and `delete []` simply detected the corruption when it's doing its thing.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `cull`, the array `array` gets created with size 0 (`intEls` is 0 when `new unsigned [intEls]` is called.)

The `array[intEls++]` are already incorrect, an array allocated with `new[]` cannot be resized. They don't cause an error because C++ does not do automatic bounds checking on arrays (would cause overhead). It is *undefined behavior*, meaning it can possibly fail in any way.

A fix of this program would be to just allocate the array with `new unsigned[els]` instead.

A better way would be to use `std::vector<unsigned>` instead of raw arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating an array with zero size.  You are then writing data into that memory, which is undefined behavior.

```
intEls = 0;
unsigned * array = new unsigned[intEls];
//                              ^^^^^^  this should be els
```

Comment: *Allocating* an array of size 0 with `new[]` is perfectly legal. The behavior is defined. Until `std::array`, this was basically the only way to legally create a zero-sized array in C++ (now `std::array` is another). Accessing elements of such array is, of course, UB.

Comment: Hmm, yet possibly pointless.  I'd like to check the standard for that.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: It's like `malloc(0)` - which is also defined.